# Combine Multiple Query Results in MySQL (by column)

Tags: mysql, join

I have 4 different queries and each of them return individual unique set of Results.
I need to combine the Query Results with using a single query.

my sample queries are:

```
1. select cls.* from (calls as cls inner join calls_users as clsusr on cls.id=clsusr.call_id) inner join users as usr on usr.id=cls.assigned_user_id where cls.assigned_user_id='seed_max_id'

2. select mtn.* from (meetings as mtn inner join meetings_users as mtnusr on mtn.id=mtnusr.meeting_id) inner join users as usr on usr.id=mtn.assigned_user_id where mtn.assigned_user_id='seed_max_id'

3. select tsk.* from tasks as tsk inner join users as usr on usr.id=tsk.assigned_user_id where tsk.assigned_user_id='seed_max_id'

4. select nts.* from (notes as nts inner join accounts as acnts on acnts.id=nts.parent_id) inner join users as usr on usr.id=acnts.assigned_user_id where acnts.assigned_user_id='seed_max_id'
```

I tried the following way, but it didn't work

```
Combine: SELECT tbl1.*, tbl2.* 
from (select cls.* from (calls as cls inner join calls_users as clsusr on cls.id=clsusr.call_id) inner join users as usr on usr.id=cls.assigned_user_id where cls.assigned_user_id='seed_max_id') as tbl1 
left  outer join
(select mtn.* from (meetings as mtn inner join meetings_users as mtnusr on mtn.id=mtnusr.meeting_id) inner join users as usr on usr.id=mtn.assigned_user_id where mtn.assigned_user_id='seed_max_id') as tbl2
using(assigned_user_id)
```

i also tried right outer join and other inner joins
I am really stuck, if any one know the solution then please help.
I need the similar result like [How can I join two tables with different number of rows in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1792850/mysql-join-two-tables-with-different-number-of-rows-and-one-same-column-name).

Data Sample:

From Query 1:

```
+-------------------------------------------+------------------+-
| Call Name                                 | Call Description |
+-------------------------------------------+------------------+-
| Discuss Review Process                    | NULL             |
| Get More information on the proposed deal | NULL             |
| Left a message                            | NULL             |
| Discuss Review Process                    | NULL             |
+-------------------------------------------+------------------+
```

From Query 2:

```
+-----------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------
| Meeting Name          | Meeting Description
+-----------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------
| Review needs          | Meeting to discuss project plan and hash out the details o
| Initial discussion    | Meeting to discuss project plan and hash out the details o
| Demo                  | Meeting to discuss project plan and hash out the details o
| Discuss pricing       | Meeting to discuss project plan and hash out the details o
| Review needs          | Meeting to discuss project plan and hash out the details o
+-----------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------
```

i need to combine the columns like the following:

```
+-------------------------------------------+------------------+-------------------+-------------------+
| Call Name                                 | Call Description |Meeting Name       |Meeting Description|
+-------------------------------------------+------------------+-------------------+-------------------+
| Discuss Review Process                    | NULL             |Review needs       |Meeting to discuss |
| Get More information on the proposed deal | NULL             |Initial discussion |Meeting to discuss |
| Left a message                            | NULL             |Demo               |Meeting to discuss |
| NULL                                   | NULL             |Discuss pricing    |Meeting to discuss |
| NULL                                      | NULL             |Review needs       |Meeting to discuss |
+-------------------------------------------+------------------+-------------------+-------------------+
```

Comment: You need to describe what the tables look like, what the result set should look like and how to combine the data.

Comment: I need to know, is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The best you can do is a UNION or UNION ALL but this requires them to have the same type and number of columns. For example:

```
SELECT 'Customer' AS type, id, name FROM customer
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Supplier', id, name FROM supplier
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Employee', id, full_name FROM employee
```

The column names don't have to match. The aliases from the first part will be used for the rest.

I'll also add that instead of:

```
select cls.* from (calls as cls inner join calls_users as clsusr on cls.id=clsusr.call_id) inner join users as usr on usr.id=cls.assigned_user_id where cls.assigned_user_id='seed_max_id'
```

you should remove the unnecessary subquery and just do:

```
SELECT c.*
FROM calls c
JOIN calls_users cu ONc.id = cu.call_id
WHERE c.assigned_user_id = 'seed_max_id'
```

There's no need for the extra complexity and the above is eminently more readable.

Comment: This can't be done in UNION, because i need to combine columns of the queries.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want your example to return a single row combining the corresponding entries from all these tables. Try this and tell us if it worked:

```
select * from users as usr
left outer join (calls as cls 
    inner join calls_users as clsusr 
    on cls.id = clsusr.call_id) 
on usr.id = cls.assigned_user_id 

left outer join (meetings as mtn 
    inner join meetings_users as mtnusr 
    on mtn.id = mtnusr.meeting_id) 
on usr.id = mtn.assigned_user_id 

left outer join tasks as tsk 
on usr.id = tsk.assigned_user_id 

left outer join (notes as nts 
    inner join accounts as acnts 
    on acnts.id=nts.parent_id) 
on usr.id = acnts.assigned_user_id 

where user.id = 'seed_max_id'
```