# Mysql query for getting values from two tables

Tags: mysql, sql

i have two tables as below-

table1 
mysql> select * from Access_ID           ;

```
+------------+----------------+
| SERVICE_ID | ACCESS_LIST_ID |
+------------+----------------+
|       1035 |           1040 |
|       1094 |           1134 |
```

table2
mysql> select * from PROFILE                  ;

```
+-------+------------------------+-------------+-
| PR_ID | PR_NAME                | PR_PARENTID | PR_TYPE           |
---------------------------------------------------------------------
|  1035 | raj                    |        1022 | name           |
|  1040 | computer               |        1035 | course         |
|  1094 | suresh                 |        1077 | name           |
|  1134 | electronics            |        1077 | course         |
```

i require below output as

table

```
| raj      |  computer  |
| suresh   | electronics|
```

Comment: What's the foreign key linking those 2 tables???

Comment: i dont know much about sql.. from first table we can get matching ID's and second table we need to match names

Comment: possible duplicate of [Combine Multiple Query Results in MySQL (by column)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2126692/combine-multiple-query-results-in-mysql-by-column)

Comment: This doesn't look like a dup; that's a question about someone who wants to do a join but there are no columns that could be joined; this one, although it's not at all clear, doesn't look like a job for the same solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

May be something like this

```
SELECT T2.PR_NAME AS NAME,T3.PR_NAME AS Serveice
FROM Access_ID T1 JOIN PROFILE T2 ON T1.SERVICE_ID = T2.PR_ID 
                  JOIN PROFILE T3 ON T1.ACCESS_LIST_ID = T3.PR_ID
```

**[FIDDLE DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ee138/6)**

*Output would be*

```
  +---------+-------------+
  | NAME    | SERVEICE    |
  +---------+-------------+
  | raj     | computer    |
  | suresh  | electronics |
  +---------+-------------+
```

Comment: + 1 You rock man! Good statement and execution plan is also perfect. Optimized Query for the desired output.

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
select
    pro1.PR_NAME
   ,pro2.PR_NAME
from 
    Access_ID acs inner join 
    PROFILE pro1 on
        (acs.SERVICE_ID = pro1.PR_ID) inner join
    PROFILE pro2 on
        (acs.ACCESS_LIST_ID = pro2.PR_ID)
```

Answer (score 0):

**This query may help you**

```
    SELECT p1.PR_NAME as Name, p2.PR_NAME as Service 
    FROM Access_ID as aid 
    LEFT JOIN PROFILE as p1 ON aid.SERVICE_ID = p1.PR_ID
    LEFT JOIN PROFILE as p2 ON aid.SERVICE_ID = p2.ACCESS_LIST_ID
```