# Join 2 select queries with 2 results into one query with one result?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, join

What I try to accomplish is that I want to select one row from tableA and one row from tableB and combine the results (comlumn names are different).

The layout of tableA is this:

```
+----------------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------------------+----------------+
| Field                      | Type         | Null | Key | Default             | Extra          |
+----------------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------------------+----------------+
| user_id                    | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL                | auto_increment |
| nickname                   | varchar(32)  | NO   |     | NULL                |                |
| password                   | varchar(129) | NO   |     | NULL                |                |
| mafia_id                   | int(11)      | NO   |     | 0                   |                |
+----------------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------------------+----------------+
```

and of tableB this:

```
+-------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field       | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| mafia_id    | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| mafia_name  | varchar(32) | NO   |     |         |                |
| mafia_tag   | varchar(5)  | NO   |     |         |                |
| mafia_color | int(11)     | NO   |     | 0       |                |
| mafia_car   | int(11)     | NO   |     | 0       |                |
| mafia_base  | int(11)     | NO   |     | 0       |                |
+-------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

I tried queries like:

```
SELECT *
FROM users

WHERE users.nickname = 'Gamer_Z'

UNION

SELECT * FROM mafia
WHERE mafia.mafia_id = (
    SELECT users.mafia_id
    FROM users
    WHERE users.nickname = 'Gamer_Z'
);
```

and this:

```
SELECT *
FROM users
WHERE nickname = 'Gamer_Z'
INNER JOIN mafia ON mafia.mafia_id = users.mafia_id;
```

But those queries give errors, I tried several others but these ones look, well, good?

I read these questions too:

[How can I join two tables with different number of rows in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1792850/mysql-join-two-tables-with-different-number-of-rows-and-one-same-column-name)

[Combine Multiple Query Results in MySQL (by column)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2126692/combine-multiple-query-results-in-mysql-by-column)

But I can't seem to fix my problem.

The output format I would like is this:

```
|users.user_id|users.nickname|users.password|users.mafia_id|mafia.mafia_name|mafia.mafia_tag|mafia.mafia_color|mafia.mafia_car|mafia.mafia_base|
```

How can I build the correct query for what I try to accomplish in MySQL(5)?
Thanks in advance!

\EDIT::

---

I almost forgot one thing! IF the mafia_id doesn't exists in tableB then there stil has to be the tableA row retured. (so the user is not in a mafia, I just load the default user data)

Comment: Give us an example result set and we can help you with a query to produce it. The problem is that you have parent and child data, where the child has multiple rows for each parent. Do you want the parent data to be repeated for each child row? Do you want the child rows to be displayed in columns at the end of the single parent row? Why do you want to combine the resultsets, anyway?

Comment: Your first option with UNION seems like the wrong way to go. The second option looks better but maybe has some syntax problems. Try moving the WHERE line to the end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to put the `WHERE` condition after the `JOIN`, not before it:

```
SELECT    *
FROM      users a
LEFT JOIN mafia b ON a.mafia_id = b.mafia_id
WHERE     a.nickname = 'Gamer_Z'
```

Comment: Ha, I didn't even look at that. Good catch. :)

Comment: works perfect but I can only accept in 9 minutes, and @ErikE, you sir just brainf*ked me with your previous comment xD

Comment: also do  you know how I can force to return a row if the mafia_id does not exist in tableB ?

Comment: It seems to return no results if the mafia_id in tableB doesn't exist ; /

Comment: @GamErix, that's what a `LEFT JOIN` does. If there is no corresponding `mafia_id` in the `mafia` table, the values in the joined columns will be `NULL`.

Answer (score 0):

the join is wrong

should be

SELECT * 
FROM   users a 
JOIN   mafia b ON a.mafia_id = b.mafia_id and a.nickname = 'Gamer_Z'

Comment: I think that effectively repeating someone else's answer without showing additional effort or information is a bit frowned on... ?

Comment: agree - the answer was not there when i posted - but they did post first so will agree with your point